# 'Update' like behavior for Google Datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a way to make query for Google Datastore that behaves the same way as SQL 'Update' query with conditions. Or should I perform this task in two parts - retrieve stored entities that match specified conditions, change appropriated property and make batch request to save changed entities?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make such a query in Google App Engine. You need first to get the entities you want to update and then modify them and store them back to datastore.